# Change <p:selectOneListbox selected value server side with JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to press a button and change p:selectOneMenu selected value
 **on the server side code** if certains conditions are met .

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myObject.id_state}" id="changeid_state" 
immediate="true" valueChangeListener="#{home.changeState}"  onchange="this.form.submit()" widgetVar="wdgId_state">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Open"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Close"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem is that if I change myObject.id_state value on the server side, when the page reloads it takes its old value back.
I've tried disabling wdgId_state when the button is pressed with no luck.

So, what could I do to set selectOneMenu value on server side with a different value?

Comment: If your code generates the `myObject.id_state` object everytime you reload the page (RequestScope) then you are missing the new value after clicking the button.
Maybe you have to change the scope of the bean to ViewScope or even SessionScope.

Comment: Don't use `onchange="this.form.submit()"`, use `p:ajax` instead

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is that when reloading the page, the old value is back, then maybe your backbean is request scope, so change it to view scope.